# am trying to return 204 no content for every return except when [Route("api/v1/status/0")] or [Route("api/v1/status/1")] is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Need to return 204 -No content 
In

```
[Route("api/v1/status/1") ]
```

and

```
[Route("api/v1/status/0")]
```

all routes other than this need to return 204 -No content,even when its page not found.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/status/")]
public ActionResult<string> Status()
{
    try
    {
        return Ok("{}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(204);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/status/0")]
    public ActionResult<string> StatusZero()
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("StatusZero() called");
        return Ok("{}");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/status/1")]
    public ActionResult<StatusResponse> StatusOne()
    {           
        var result = new StatusResponse
        {
            ContainerId = Environment.MachineName,
            Version = "v1"
        };
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

The above sample gives the code snipet i would like to return status code 204 for 
anyother invalid call coming to the status API

Comment: Can you show please what you have tried so far?

Comment: am trying to hit the status with all values ,but am not able to hit the to the status api  [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/v1/status/")]
        public ActionResult<string> Status()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("StatusZero() called");
                return Ok("{}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(204);
            } and trying to return status code (204 ) from catch

Comment: Share us your request, and your expected result for different scenario. It's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: api/v1/status/15 ,api/v1/status/abcd ,api/v1/status/ref should return a 204 no content rather than 404 page not found,That is what am looking at .

Answer (score 0):

If your code does not return any value, you will get 204 status in response. Example for the below code if your DB has alias as 0 & 1, if you pass 2. The response will be 204.

```
// GET api/authors/ardalis
[HttpGet("{alias}")]
public Author Get(string alias)
{
    return _authorRepository.GetByAlias(alias);
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#content-negotiation)